# Вывод древа категорий из БД как на примере

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как реализован выбор категорий в базе данных как на примере? Не могу понять логику как значения хранятся и взаимодействую. Одно дело когда просто подгружаешь список, а тут ветви категорий. Пример: "Недвижимость -> Квартиры -> Продать"

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего сложного.

Например:
- Есть таблица countries (id, title)
- Есть таблица regions (id, title, id_country)
- Есть таблица city (id, title, id_region)

1. Первым запросом получаем список всех стран из таблицы countries.
2. Вторым запросом получаем список регионов по стране из таблицы regions передавая при этом id_country
3. Третьим запросом получаем список городов из таблицы city передавая при этом id_region

Возможно, это вас натолкнет на правильную мысль)